# Find a suitable large topology for convergence

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $F := [0,1]^{(0,1)}$ of functions $f: (0,1) \to [0,1]$ and the sequence $f_n \in F$ defined by $f_n(x) := \sin(\pi n x)$, $x \in (0,1)$. Clearly, $f_n$ is not converging pointwise at any point in $(0,1)$, i.e. not in the (Hausdorff) product topology when $[0,1]$ is equipped with the usual Euclidean topology. A topology in which $f_n$ is converging is of course the (non-Hausdorff) trivial topology $\tau_t$. But then $f_n$ converges to any $f \in F$.

Is there some topology stronger than $\tau_t$ in which $f_n$ is converging? Can one speak of the strongest topology in which $f_n$ is converging?

The goal is to find somehow a "natural" space in which $f_n$ can be considered as an object and have a unique "meaningful" limit. As an example, if we equip $F$ with $\tau_t$ then the Kolmogorov quotient is just a singleton $\{ g \}$ and $f_n = g \to g$ in $\{ g \}$.

Comment: Choose any funtion you would like this sequence to converge to, lets call it $f$. Now let $\tau$ be the topology consisting of all subsets which contain $f$ and for some $N$ contain all $f_n$ where $n$  is greater than $N$. This gives many stronger topologies than $\tau_t$.

Comment: I see. This topology is also some kind of "trivial topology" $\tau_{f_n}$ corresponding to the sequence $f_n$. First of all, the chosen limit point $f$ seems to be irrelevant: by construction of $\tau_{f_n}$, in this topology the sequence $f_n$ converges to every point $g \in F$, since every open set contains eventually all $f_n$ (and also $f$) and in particular every open neighborhood of $g$ contains eventually all $f_n$. Other sequences may not converge (in contrast to the trivial topology $\tau_t$).

Comment: If you want a topology which only converges to that fixed $f$. We could add all subsets that don't contain $f$.

Comment: This also proves that there isn't a strongest topology.

Comment: Ok, every singleton $\{ g \}$ with $g \neq f$ is open, so that it is a join of the discrete topology on $F \setminus \{f\}$ and $\tau_{f_n}$. Is there some "natural" topology when we consider the concrete definition of the functions $f_n = \sin(\pi n x)$ that are oscillating (without an a-priori choice of a wishful limit $f$)? By "natural" I mean that $f_n$ seems to be strongly oscillating such that it somehow "wishes" to identify many "oscillating" limits. (Usually, such sequences arise in spaces of distributions in functional analysis, but it is also interesting to consider it on $F$.)